Separate keypad just for macros
I use Autokey for about twenty different hotkeys using combination of control, alt, shift, and the numbers pad. I'd like to have an auxiliary keypad like this one so I don't have to use the numbers pad on my keyboard and use the aux pad on my laptop.
My question is: would ubuntu recognize the key codes as separate from the regular keyboard, or as just another set of, say, numbers keys? Instead of Ctrl+NumPad4 it could be Ctrl+AuxKey4 ? Is that how it works?
